# Spring-data-couchbase - running update query

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

Is any possibility to execute N1QL update query using spring-data?

I.e. I have following update query:

```
"UPDATE USERS USE KEYS $id SET location = $location"
```

I tried to use `couchbaseTemplate.queryN1QL` method, but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution of this problem using spring data or even native couchbase java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `CouchbaseTemplate` is more tailored towards Spring Data document's use case, so it expects to run queries that return specific elements and will end up unmarshalled into entities (eg. a `User` object).

if you want to run a more freeform query, like your update, you can always access the native SDK from the template. In your case:

```
String paStatement = "UPDATE USERS USE KEYS $id SET location = $location";
JsonObject paramValues = JsonObject.create().put("id", theId).put("location", "theLocation");
N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.parametrized(paStatement, paramValues);
template.getCouchbaseBucket().query(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `RETURNING *` at the end of your `UPDATE` statement. It would make the statement returns something. It works for me.